# How to use scipy's fminbound function when function returns a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have simple function for which I want to calculate the minimum value

```
from scipy import optimize
def f(x):
    return x**2

optimize.fminbound(f, -1, 2)
```

This works fine. Now I modify above function which now returns a `dictionary`

```
def f1(x):
    y = x ** 2
    return_list = {}
    return_list['x'] = x
    return_list['y'] = y
    return return_list
```

While it is returning multiple objects `x and y`, I want to apply `fminbound` only on `y`, the other object `x` is just for informational purpose for other use of this function.

How can I use `fminbound` for this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple wrapper function that extracts `y`:

```py
def f1(x):
    y = x ** 2
    return_list = {}
    return_list['x'] = x
    return_list['y'] = y
    return return_list

optimize.fminbound(lambda x: f1(x)['y'], -1, 2)
```